# How do I connect Docker Airflow container to local machine, so that I can write/save files to local machine?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have a file called hello_world.py saved in my dag folder, that contains the following code.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

def helloWorld():
    f= open("C:\\Users\\username\\test.txt","w+")
    f.write("hello world")
    f.close()
    
   
with DAG(dag_id="hello_world",
         start_date=datetime(2021,1,1),
         schedule_interval="@hourly",
         catchup=False) as dag:
    
        task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='hello_world',
        python_callable=helloWorld)
        
task1
```

When I execute this through airflow which is running from Docker on windows. It says that it is successful, however, when I go to the folder there is no text file called "test.txt".

Is there a setting to allow me to access the host machine, if so where?  I have seen `host.docker.internal` mentioned in a few other answers to questions similar to mine, but I'm not sure where I am supposed to enter that.

Answer (score 1):

Your Airflow docker can not access the host machine unless you bind a volume that map between a folder in the host to a folder in the docker.
If you are using a docker-compose you can defined this volume where the dags/plugins and logs are defined

```
volumes:
- ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
- ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
- ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
- //c/Users/username:/my_home
```

Comment: Thanks! While this did work, I have a lot of scripts that I need to place in multiple places.  It seems unintuitive to have to keep manually binding volumes in the compose.  I thought you could add `host.docker.internal` into the compose file using `extra_hosts` and this would allow the docker container to not only access you host but share your hosts credentials. However, when using the airflow yaml file, I don't know where to add this.